# unknown string to raw string

Tags: python, string, tkinter, pytube

So i have a browse button that indicates a path for a download but since it puts out a regular string it  won't download since there are backslashes involved and they aren't litteraly interpreted. Edit: I added other parts of my code a bit since some parts weren't really clear.

```
def browse():
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    Path = filename
    print(Path)
BROWSEbutton = tk.Button(src, text="Browse", font="Courier 12", command=browse).place(x=425,y=0)
def Convert():
    try:   
        video = yt.YouTube(URL.get()).streams.first()
        try:
            video.download(Path)
            print("succesful")
        except:
            print("error")
            msgb.showerror("Error","Invalid Path")     
    except:
        print("error")    
        msgb.showerror("Error","Invalid URL")
CONVERTbutton = tk.Button(src, text="Convert", font="Courier 12",command=Convert).place(x=243,y=220)
```

Comment: Better print the exception message as well.

Comment: The interpretation of backslashes shoudn't matter. What happens when you run your code. How do you know they aren't being handled properly?

Comment: If your indentation here matches your actual code, then `browse()` is a completely useless function - it asks the user to select a directory, and then fails to store the user's choice in any place that will still exist after the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are defining a global variable such as `folder_path` and you are not using it
2. The path in convert() is not defined in that function where the global variable `folder_path` should have been used.
3. And the path given by `filedialog.askdirectory()` also works for `video.download()`

after removing these mistakes your code should be,

```
folder_path=""
def browse():
    global folder_path
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(folder_path)

def Convert():
    global folder_path
    try:   
        video = yt.YouTube(URL.get()).streams.first()
        try:
            video.download(folder_path)
            print("succesful")
        except:
            print("error")
            msgb.showerror("Error","Invalid Path")     
    except:
        print("error")    
        msgb.showerror("Error","Invalid URL")

BROWSEbutton = tk.Button(src, text="Browse", font="Courier 12", command=browse).place(x=425,y=0)
CONVERTbutton = tk.Button(src, text="Convert", font="Courier 12",command=Convert).place(x=243,y=220)
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: **1.** Your example show the common pitfall: [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759). **2.** Inside `Convert` there is no `global folder_path` needed, you read the variable. **3.** No exception type(s) specified (bare-except) is bad practice.